# Present Specific Storyboard/View on first app launch

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I'm building an app that is going to require a registration on the initial launch of the app.  I'm used to using nibs and presenting those but how would I present this view modally and then dismiss it once the registration is complete.

Also would it be better to just have a view in the storyboard or a separate storyboard (I'm assuming the former.)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to have a separate view in the storyboard (login or registration view). If user is not logged in, you'll show it:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourLoginViewIdentifier"];
[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Pretty much the same approach, which you used.

Comment: It's actually going to be a table view controller because it's a static table view with firm elements.  So will it still work?

Comment: presentViewController... is a method of UIViewController. UITableViewController inherits from it. so.. yes, it'll work.

Comment: @EvanStoddard you should accept answer if it helped. Thanks.